# DAX Average Issue

Tags: dax

I have this table 
[image]

and this is the measurement i have to calculate the average

Traded Contract(MTD) := TOTALMTD(SUM([Traded Contract]), 'TestTable'([Trading Date]))

Average := [Traded Contract(MTD)]/SUM([Trading Days])

Currently the result of average is correct up to daily level,
When I wish to see the monthly average, I didn’t filter by date, then I will get the result 9000/14 = 642 which is incorrect, I wish to see 4425 which is the total of each average. How do I amend my Average measurement query to get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this since 4425 isn't really an average, but you can write your formula as follows:

```
Average = SUMX(VALUES(TestTable[Trading Date]),
               [Traded Contract(MTD)] /
               LOOKUPVALUE(TestTable[Trading Days],
                           TestTable[Trading Date],[Trading Date]))
```

For more information on how these sort of measures work, I suggest reading the following article:
[Subtotals and Grand Totals That Add Up “Correctly”](https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/03/subtotals-and-grand-totals-that-add-up-correctly/)